# SSRS 2008 Row width changes when toggled

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that uses a toggle in a "parent row" of a tablix to show the row below.  In this "child" row there is an embedded tablix in merged cells.  My problem is that when the toggle is flipped to display the child row, the parent row expands.  Anybody else seen behavior like this?

Answer (score 0):

On the cell(s) that are expanding, set the growth properties (CanGrow, CanShrink) - in this case, it sounds like you'd want CanGrow=False.

Comment: All cells are set to CanGrow=False for this section of the report.

Comment: Have you checked all cells in the column (such as the header)?  If any cell in the column needs to grow, the entire column will.  Other things to look for: contents of the cell forcing growth, other objects on the report aligned with the left or right border of the column that may be causing it to move (put the tablix into a rectangle).  Can you post a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: I ended up copying a tablix that was already working properly, changed the dataset, and all the data displayed.  It works now.  Not sure what caused it and I have saved a copy of the report that isn't working so that I can try to troubleshoot it later.  Just had to get this deployed for now.